# Scala type constraints confusing error

Tags: scala, traits, design-by-contract, type-constraints

This code:

```
trait Base[+K <: Option[Int]] {
  val a: K = None
}

class GuaranteedA extends Base[Some[Int]] {
  override val a = Some(1)
}
```

produces an error:

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : None.type
 required: K
             val a: K = None
```

But why?
The type constraint in `K` says `K` must be a subtype of `Option[Int]` which `None` is, even when I try to `val a: K = Some(0)` in `Base`, the same error is produced.

I'm very confused of this behavior and have no idea why this happens, maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`trait Base[K <: Option[Int]]` just says that: There is a type `K` which is subtype of `Option[Int]`. Your second part `GaranteedA` shows exactly why your `Base` definition cannot pretend that `None` is a subtype of `K`—imagine that you did *not* override `val a`. You would end up having value `None` cast to a `Some`.

Just because `K` is a subtype of `Option[Int]` and `None` is a subtype of `Option[Int]`, does not guarantee that `None` is a subtype of `K`.